# How to convert point coordinates to point geometry in a different spatial reference coordinate system?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, srid

I have point coordinates returned with wkid 3857 and need to convert to 4326 to get point geometry using PostGIS. I know I can return geometry of the same type using the following:

`ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lat,long),4326)`

How can I convert points from a different spatial reference system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to setsrid or transform.

Hope this will be useful. http://postgis.net/2013/08/30/tip_ST_Set_or_Transform/

Comment: `ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lat,long),3857),4326)` did the trick

Comment: I used this link for many years! but It's not working anymore :(

Comment: @GeoBeez see here for the content of that original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318176/5031762